# Add user to local group on remote computer using different credentials

Tags: windows, shell, active-directory

I have credentials for the local "Administrator" user on every computer in my department. Sometimes, when I set the machines up for my colleagues, I forget to add my domain username in the administrators group (whoopsie!). It would be easy just setting up a remote desktop connection passing the Administrator user credential, but I'd like to do this "silently", so my question is: is there a way to pass those credentials by shell and then perform the usual operations for adding a user (mine, in this case) to the administrators group?

I work with Windows machines in an Active Directory environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not from the shell, but you could from your PC/Server as admin run computer management, right click "Computer Management (local)" select "connect to another computer" and bring up the remote computers computer management console and add yourself to that computers local admin group in the background.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I've thought about that, but it's the whole "log off and log in" thing that I'd like to avoid. Thanks anyway

Comment: I may have read this wrong, and sorry to perhaps point out the obvious. If you mean for you to log off your machine and then logon to your machine as a domain admin to do this, you can just lauch "computer manager" "as a different user" while you are logged in with say a standard account. Again sorry if I am miss understanding.